# Create Columns in Dataframe Inside Loop With Filters Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, pyspark, databricks

I want to create columns for each element in list "weeks" and have them be all in one dataframe. Dataframe "df" is filtered based on "weeknum" then the columns are created. At the time it runs but the end dataframe only contains information about the last "weeknum". How can I create the columns for all "weeknum" joined left?

I tried this:

```
weeks = [24, 25]
for weeknum in weeks:
    df_new = df.filter(df.week == weeknum).groupBy(['gender', 'pro']).pivot("share").agg(first('forecast_units')) \
        .withColumnRenamed('0.01', 'units_1_share_wk'+str(weeknum))\
        .withColumnRenamed('0.1', 'units_10_share_wk'+str(weeknum))\
        .withColumnRenamed('0.15', 'units_15_share_wk'+str(weeknum))\
        .withColumnRenamed('0.2', 'units_20_share_wk'+str(weeknum)) 
df_new.show()
```

But this only returns the dataframe with the last "weeknum" in "weeks".

The original dataframe "df" looks like this:

```
|country|gender|order_date|         pro|share|        prediction|week|dayofweek|forecast_units|
+-------+------+----------+------------+-------------+------------------+----+---------+-------------------+
| ES|  Male|2022-09-15|Jeans - Flat|         0.01|13.322306632995605|  37|        5|               93.0|
| ES|  Male|2022-09-15|Jeans - Flat|          0.1| 19.09369468688965|  37|        5|              134.0|
| ES|  Male|2022-09-15|Jeans - Flat|         0.15|22.504554748535156|  37|        5|              158.0|
```

I want the end dataframe to have the following structure:

```
|gender|pro|units_1_tpr_wk24|units_10_tpr_wk24|units_15_tpr_wk24|units_20_tpr_wk24|units_1_tpr_wk25|units_10_tpr_wk25|units_15_tpr_wk25|units_20_tpr_wk25|
```

Expected Output:

```
|gender|pro|units_1_tpr_wk24|units_10_tpr_wk24|units_15_tpr_wk24|units_20_tpr_wk24|units_1_tpr_wk25|units_10_tpr_wk25|units_15_tpr_wk25|units_20_tpr_wk25|
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+|
|Female|Belts|28.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|28.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|
|Female|Dress|0.0|44.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|
|Male|Belts|0.0|0.0|33.0|0.0|28.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|
|Male|Suits|0.0|0.0|0.0|34.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|
```

Comment: You are overwriting ```df_new``` in every loop, so you will only see the latest filtered df. What exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Just updated the expected output. I want a dataframe similar to that one. Is it possible inside a loop? Mine overwrites and only has the columns for the last week.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest generating all of the required columns first, and then passing it into a `select` function like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

weeks = [24, 25]
cols_to_select = []
for weeknum in weeks:
    cols_to_select.extend([
        col('0.01').alias(f'units_1_share_wk{weeknum}'),
        col('0.1').alias(f'units_10_share_wk{weeknum}'),
        col('0.15').alias(f'units_15_share_wk{weeknum}'),
        col('0.2').alias(f'units_20_share_wk{weeknum}')
    ])

df.filter(df.week == weeknum).groupBy(['gender', 'pro']).pivot("share").agg(first('forecast_units')).select([col("gender"), col("pro")] + cols_to_select)
```

Comment: When I run this code I get the following error message `"AnalysisException: Column '`0`.`01`' does not exist."` . How is this fixed? Also, how does the last line contain the information for all the weeks? Doesn't the select simply add the columns?